# Providing Authorize button in Swagger UI with externalized Open API

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Suppose I have a server that retrieves an Open API from somewhere else. How do I enable the Authorize button in Swagger UI? All I need is to be able to pass a JWT as an `Authorization` request header

Here's an MRE. I hope you appreciate it. I took some time to write it (maybe too much for an MRE). Stapi is completely open, but let's imagine that it's actually some microservice and the Swagger UI server is a gateway (which is the case). It's even called "Gateway" even though it actually isn't. Also, keep in mind that the Open API for Stapi that I found is apparently stale. You won't be able to actually hit any of those endpoints (even from your browser)

That said, I'm open to suggestions involving editing the source code of the *server that supplies API documentation* (I have write access to the actual microservice)

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewaydemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewaydemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.service;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public interface ApiProvider {
    String getApiName();
    Mono<OpenAPI> getOpenApi();
}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.config;

import com.example.gatewaydemo.service.ApiProvider;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeStrategies;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
public class ApiProviderConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        int size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
        ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size))
                .build();
        return WebClient.builder()
                .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPIV3Parser openApiParser() {
        return new OpenAPIV3Parser();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiProvider stapiApiProvider(WebClient webClient, OpenAPIV3Parser parser) {
        return new ApiProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getApiName() {
                return "stapi";
            }

            @Override
            public Mono<OpenAPI> getOpenApi() {
                return webClient.get()
                        .uri("https://stapi.co/api/v1/rest/common/download/stapi.yaml")
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .map(parser::readContents)
                        .map(SwaggerParseResult::getOpenAPI);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper nullIgnoringObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.controller;

import com.example.gatewaydemo.model.SwaggerUiConfig;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
public class SwaggerUiConfigController {
    @GetMapping("/swagger-ui/config")
    public Mono<SwaggerUiConfig> getSwaggerUiConfig() {
        return Mono.just(SwaggerUiConfig.builder()
                .withConfigItemOf().url("/swagger-ui/doc/stapi").name("Star Trek API").build()
                .build());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.controller;

import com.example.gatewaydemo.service.ApiProvider;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SwaggerUiDocController {
    private final List<ApiProvider> apiProviders;
    @GetMapping("/swagger-ui/doc/{api-name}")
    public Mono<OpenAPI> getOpenApi(@PathVariable("api-name") String apiName) {
        return apiProviders.stream()
                .filter(apiProvider -> apiProvider.getApiName().equals(apiName))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow()
                .getOpenApi();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.gatewaydemo.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class SwaggerUiConfig {
    private final List<ConfigItem> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    public SwaggerUiConfig(SwaggerUiConfigBuilder builder) {
        this.urls.addAll(builder.getUrls());
    }

    public static SwaggerUiConfigBuilder builder() {
        return new SwaggerUiConfigBuilder();
    }

    @Getter
    public static class SwaggerUiConfigBuilder {
        private final List<ConfigItem> urls = new ArrayList<>();

        public ConfigItem.ConfigItemBuilder withConfigItemOf() {
            return new ConfigItem.ConfigItemBuilder(this);
        }

        public SwaggerUiConfig build() {
            return new SwaggerUiConfig(this);
        }
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public static class ConfigItem {
        private String url;
        private String name;

        private ConfigItem(ConfigItemBuilder builder) {
            this.url = builder.getUrl();
            this.name = builder.getName();
        }

        @Getter
        public static class ConfigItemBuilder {
            private final SwaggerUiConfigBuilder configBuilderInstance;
            private String url;
            private String name;

            ConfigItemBuilder(SwaggerUiConfigBuilder configBuilderInstance) {
                this.configBuilderInstance = configBuilderInstance;
            }

            public ConfigItemBuilder url(String url) {
                this.url = url;
                return this;
            }

            public ConfigItemBuilder name(String name) {
                this.name = name;
                return this;
            }

            public SwaggerUiConfigBuilder build() {
                ConfigItem configItem = new ConfigItem(this);
                configBuilderInstance.urls.add(configItem);
                return configBuilderInstance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatewaydemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gatewaydemo</name>
    <description>gatewaydemo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    config-url: /swagger-ui/config
    path: /swagger-ui
```

Hit `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui` and you should be able to see this. No `Authorize` button. I want it

[image]

Comment: Even if you don't have a complete solution but have some thoughts to share, please drop them in the comments

Comment: Just to be sure: You want to parse another Open API scheme, rebuild this scheme with Swagger on your local machine, then manipulate this Swagger copy (inserting your button) and finally do what? What is the final purpose of all of this?

Comment: @SimpleJack I want to be able to visit my Gateway's endpoints (ones that require a JWT in the `Authorization` header) via Swagger UI

Comment: I assume you cannot change the original application. The one you pull the Open API scheme from.

Comment: @SimpleJack also, I discovered that a functional `Authorize` button only somewhat depends on the received Open API. See, the microservice *does* have the button, and it seems to work fine. However, the button doesn't work in Gateway's UI: once you press it, a blank modal shows up. For the sake of experiment, I made my Gateway serve Swagger a hard-coded Open API that I took from the microservice's UI (I literally copied and pasted it). The modal was still blank

Comment: @SimpleJack as I said in the question, I'm open to suggestions involving editing the source code of the server that supplies API documentation. It even may be a better option (services may offer different forms of authorization, not just JWT-based)

Comment: If the original server already provided a Swagger UI **with** the button, in other words: the original server already provides everything you need, then why not simply reroute this server? You don't have to rebuild anything. Just use your application as proxy...

Comment: @SimpleJack I'm not sure I understand you. My gateway is supposed to aggregate endpoints of all applications hooked up to the same Eureka (including in its UI)

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand your problem. As you described it in your question, I assumed you have just one other application, that's why i was so confused what are you even doing...
You want to collect several APIs and merge them into one..., lets call it "fat" API (from Java fat JAR).

Answer (score 0):

Activate JWT authorization globally on your Springdoc application (@see [**Springdocs DOCs**](https://springdoc.org/#how-do-i-add-authorization-header-in-requests)):

```java
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info(
                title = "My API collection",
                version = "1.0",
                description = "Collection of several other APIs",
                contact = @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Contact(name = "ACME Inc.", url = "www.example.com", email = "support@acme.com")
        )
)
public class OpenAPIConfig {

        @Bean
        public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
                Components newComponents = new Components();
                newComponents.addSecuritySchemes("bearer-key", new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP).scheme("bearer").bearerFormat("JWT").name("My JWT"));
                return new OpenAPI().components(newComponents);
        }
}
```

Problem with that, this is globally. The authentication header is now by default in every request. Also, I don't think you have any further controll. Because Springdoc generates the scheme from meta-annotations from your Java methods. You don't have any of that. This means you had to manipulate the scheme file. This is doable, but extremely time-consuming.

---

#### Just some thoughts:

Instead of merging every API into one, maybe you should consider building a [**Spring Gateway**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/index.html) that simply reroutes to single servers/APIs. With that you would prevent the problems from above...

Comment: Thank you, but have you tried it with my MRE? I pasted your config there, and the button is still absent

Comment: I also tried pasting it into my service. Again, as before, a button is present *and functional* in the service's UI but disfunctional in the gateway's UI (blank modal on click)

Comment: Also, I *am* using Spring Cloud Gateway. I can't just route to the service's API since the Gateway's endpoints are not idential to those of the service